# How to iterate json data with img tag in Angular4

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to bind the img url from api response. Here I have attached what I have tried so far.

Json data structure :

[image]

This is the structure of data I received from API

my-cart.component.ts

```
 this.CartdataService.get_Product_Details(this.productCode).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.productDetails = data;
      this.productImages = this.productDetails['0']['PROD_B']
      console.log(this.productImages);
    });
```

Receiving array of data in console

[image]

Here console I got the image url in an array.

HTML code

```
<img *ngFor="let images of productImages; let i = index" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event)" [src]="images['PRODUCT_THUMBNAIL']"
              [alt]="'img' + i" class="img-thumbnail" [attr.ref]="images[i]['PRODUCT_IMAGE']">
```

This is how I am trying to bind the image url from the response but I did not get the image.

Can anyone guide me to solve this.

Comment: Can you show the elements in the dom tree through devtools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they way you are assigning images are wrong.

Try with

```
  this.productImages = this.productDetails[0]['PROD_B'].
```

and also make a change of below

```
  <div  *ngFor="let images of productImages; let i = index" >
        <img (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event)" 
                  [src]="images['PRODUCT_THUMBNAIL']"
                  [alt]="'img' + i" class="img-thumbnail" 
                  [attr.ref]="images['PRODUCT_IMAGE']">
</div>
```

Comment: not worked for me ,after trying this HTML the other functionalities also get affected

Comment: this.productDetails[0] means accessing first object. It will not break. can you provide plunker or JSFiddle

Comment: That's working fine ,console also got the array of URL's but the html part is not solved my issue

Comment: what are the error you are getting for the template..? any screenshot?

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'PRODUCT_IMAGE' of undefined in console

Comment: Edited   [attr.ref]="images['PRODUCT_IMAGE']"> in the answer try that.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are missing a single quotation over the actual path..(binding the URL as a string but not an expression..) try this:

```
<img *ngFor="let images of productImages; let i = index" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event)" [src]="'images["PRODUCT_THUMBNAIL"]'"
          [alt]="'img' + i" class="img-thumbnail" [attr.ref]="'images[i]["PRODUCT_IMAGE"]'">
```

Comment: I can surely say that the single quotation will not come there

Comment: @Nikson: Did you try with something like this then: `[src]="'images[\'PRODUCT_THUMBNAIL\']'"` ?